# Vaadin Table Collapse Column Listener

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I want to know which columns are collapsed & uncollapsed, in vaadin.
Is there a listener for this, I could not found?

Comment: this is still a new enhancement, not provided yet. http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/6914

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported out the box. However you could extends Table to support it.

Something like

```
public class ColumnCollapsedObservableTable extends Table {

    private List<ColumCollapsedListener> collapseListeners = new ArrayList<ColumCollapsedListener>();

    @Override
    public void setColumnCollapsed(Object propertyId, boolean collapsed)
            throws IllegalStateException {

        super.setColumnCollapsed(propertyId, collapsed);
        fireColumnCollapsedEvent(new ColumnCollapsedEvent(this, propertyId, collapsed));
    }

    public void addColumnCollapsedListener(ColumnCollapsedListener l) {
        ...
    }

    public void removeColumnCollapsedListener(ColumnCollapsedListener l) {
        ...
    }

    private fireColumnCollapsedEvent(ColumCollapsedEvent event) {
        ...
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Vaadin 7.7.5 may be also in versions before) there is a ColumnCollapseListener for that.

```
Table.addColumnCollapseListener(Table.ColumnCollapseListener listener)
```

**EDIT**

For uncollapsed events the listener method above will be called again (unfortunately with exact same arguments of the given Event object so that there is no way to make a difference between collapsing and uncollapsing event)