# How to handle action of 'setColumnCollapsingAllowed' on filter table? how to get affected column name or item id in VAADIN?

Tags: java, ejb, vaadin

I am storing affected columns on hide/show action column in cookies, using `setColumnCollapsingAllowed` in vaadin.

How to get column name affected after hiding columns. Is there any listener available?

```java
pagedFilterTable.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a listener `ColumnCollapseListener` avalailable in `Table` class. You can add it via  this API : [addColumnColapseListener](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/7.7.17/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#addColumnCollapseListener-com.vaadin.ui.Table.ColumnCollapseListener-)

Also, there seems to be an example on someone's Github project here  : [adding listener](https://github.com/artyom366/spring-boot-security-vaadin/blob/master/src/main/java/ee/erp/central/user/layouts/UserLayout.java#L72)

And the discussion on similar matter was here: [Vaadin Table Collapse Column Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905411/vaadin-table-collapse-column-listener)